# In what format does ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(Object) display dates?

Tags: java, date, reflection, tostring, apache-commons-lang

In what format does [`ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(Object)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html#reflectionToString%28java.lang.Object%29) display dates?  According to the [Apache Commons Lang 2.4 documentation](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/index.html), `ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(Object)` delegates to [`ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(Object)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%29) which "Builds a `toString` value using the default `ToStringStyle` through reflection."  So, in what format does the default [`ToStringStyle`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringStyle.html) display dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DefaultToStringStyle`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#RDk_icqX2EA/tags/LANG_2_4/src/java/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringStyle.java&q=ReflectionToStringBuilder&d=1&l=2117) is just an immutable subclass of `ToStringStyle`, so it falls back on that for handling.  `ToStringStyle` does not have any special handling for dates, so it just uses `Date`'s `toString`.

However, there is actually an [example](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#RDk_icqX2EA/tags/LANG_2_4/src/java/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringStyle.java&q=ReflectionToStringBuilder&d=1&l=50) of adding it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ToStringBuilder {

    /**
     * The default style of output to use.
     */
    private static ToStringStyle defaultStyle = ToStringStyle.DEFAULT_STYLE;
```

The default toString style. Using the Person example from ToStringBuilder, the output would look like this:

```
Person@182f0db[name=John Doe,age=33,smoker=false]
```

Comment: Jon, thank you for your answer, but this doesn't tell me how `ToStringStyle.DEFAULT_STYLE` displays a Java `Date`.