# What time zone does Date.toString() display?

Tags: java, date, timezone

By default, what time zone does method [`java.util.Date.toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) display?  Since a Java [`Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) stores a given date in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) and doesn't contain any explicit time zone, does `Date.toString()` simply display the default time zone for the host, or [`TimeZone.getDefault()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault%28%29)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It displays using `TimeZone.getDefault()` which, in turn, will default to the time zone of the operating system it is running on (i.e. the host). So in practice, they will be the same thing

Note that a Java date *is not really a date!* It is an **instant in time**, represented by a millisecond offset since the beginning of the *epoch*. It still contains methods which reference *year*, *month* etc but these are all deprecated. You should on no account be using a `Date` object as if it were a date.

Use a `Calendar` (although this is arguably even more broken than `Date`) or a decent library like JODA.

Comment: Is there any chance that given a host timezone of Eastern Standard Time (EST) that Date.toString() would sometimes display time zone EST, but other times display Eastern Daylight Time (EDT)?  I'm observing this strange behaviour with `ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(Object)` which, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198253/in-what-format-does-tostringbuilder-reflectiontostringobject-display-dates/4198295#4198295, uses `Date.toString()` to display `Date` objects.

Comment: I would think it likely that your system uses any daylight savings settings appropriate to your locale (your sys admins will know). So during the DST period, I would expect the default timezone to be EDT (assuming that EDT is the daylight saving version of EST).

Comment: My question wasn't clear enough. Given an Object that contains multiple `Date` objects, `ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(Object)` displays some dates with EST time zone and other dates with EDT. Shouldn't it display them all in the host time zone, in this case EST?

Comment: @Derek - you are using one timezone that display a date as either EST or EDT depending on the date ... not on whether "now" is in daylight savings time.  *"Shouldn't it display them all in the host time zone"* - that would be really confusing for most people.  ("I got to work at 9am on that day, but the stupid computer says it was 10am.")

Comment: Stephen C, I agree with you that this time zone output is strange, but it is not our code that is the culprit. It is either the JAX-WS reference implementation (jaxws-rt) that is confused about to which time zone to translate dates that it deserializes from an input SOAP message, or either Apache Commons Lang 2.4 ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(Object) or Date.toString() that is displaying several of the "instants in time" in the incorrect time zone. I expect the dates to display in time zone EST, the time zone of the operating system and JVM, and not EDT.

Comment: Stephen C, I think I initially misunderstood your comment.  When JAX-WS is mapping SOAP XML `xs:dateTime` elements from a client to Java `Date` objects in the server, it translate these input dates to UTC milliseconds.  However, when the server outputs the `Date` to the log, or stores the `Date` to the database, according to the answer, `Date.toString()` translates the UTC milliseconds in the `Date` to the host time zone and the JDBC driver also translates these UTC milliseconds, usually to the host time zone, though some drivers may translate it to the database server time zone.

Comment: <continued from previous comment> The problem is that the log shows some dates in EST and others in EDT, when I expect them all to be in EST.  Why the mix of time zones?

Answer (score 1):

> Does it display the default time zone
>   for the host, or
>   TimeZone.getDefault()?

The latter (which is the same as the former unless you set it explicitly somewhere). However, this is information gleamed from the source code, so it should be considered an implementation detail. If you want specific repeatable behavior, you should implement it yourself.