# How does JAX-WS map an XML date with time zone to a Java Date?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jax-ws

How does [JAX-WS](http://jax-ws.java.net/) map an [XML schema date](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp) (`xs:dateTime`) to a Java [`Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)?  In particular, if a JAX-WS server receives an `xs:dateTime` that contains a time zone, does JAX-WS translate the date to the server time zone?  For example, suppose a server running JAX-WS is given an XML date of `2010-08-20T00:00:00-04:00` and the server operates in time zone UTC-5, after JAX-WS maps the date to Java `Date` property `now`, what string would `now.toString()` produce?

Given a collection of XML dates as input, JAX-WS will map these to a collection of Java `Date` objects, but in the log, to my surprise I see a mix of EST and EDT time zones when what I expect to see is all dates in EST, the current host time zone.

Comment: Yes, I have, but I observe the strange behaviour that I describe in the comments to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199217/what-time-zone-does-date-tostring-display/4199245#4199245.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date.toString() prints the time with respect to the server's timezone.

E.g.

```
SimpleTimeZone stz = new SimpleTimeZone(-18000000, "UTC-5");
TimeZone.setDefault(stz);
```

Means that all calls to Date.toString() will be of the format `Fri Jan 01 0:00:00 GMT-5:00 2010`

Consequently, if you had a web service that took in an input `Date` and returned it without any changes, it would be changed to match the server's timezone.

If you have any further questions, I'd suggest you just play with it yourself.

Comment: This is what I'd expect, but I've observed a collection of dates that, when printed, show a mix of EST and EDT time zones.  Which library is the culprit?  Is it JAX-WS, Logback 0.9.24, Apache Commons Lang 2.4 `ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(Object)`, `Date.toString()`, `TimeZone`, the JVM?  I asked this question thinking that JAX-WS might be the cause.