# lost one day for a date

Tags: java, json, jackson, orika, spring-restcontroller

On client side, i use dd/MM/yyyy date format. The field use a twitter bootstrap 3 datetime picker (https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

I enter via twitter bootstrap 3 datetime picker 24/07/2015
in my json i sent, i see: birthdate: "24/07/2015"

In my dto, i do

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date birthdate;
```

When i receive the date on the server, in my dto  see: 23/07/2015 19:00

One day is lost.

Any explication?

Comment: have you checked your local time settings on your system ?

Comment: client / server is on the same machine: both is edt -4 hours (mtl time)...

Comment: It is most definitely a time zone translation issue.  One side is treating the time as UTC, and the other is converting to local time.  We've had this issue in some client/server integration with 3rd-party system.  The dead giveaway is the "19:00" that has been added to the other time, it is exactly 5 hours of difference (not actually a full day).

Comment: browser side i get for a new date: Fri Jul 24 2015 23:49:26 GMT-0400 (EDT).  On the server i get: Fri Jul  23:49:26 EDT 2015. I think Eastern Daylight Saving Time (EDT) = GMT-4 (USA + Canada)

Comment: If you query your service using a tool like Postman, does the date come incorrect? In my case, the problem was in the restTemplate client, not in server.

Comment: Had the same issue. Using postman to verify that the client is not the culprit. Seems like an issue with the timezone Jackson is using vs the timezone of the system. Had to change the jackson config to compensate for dates

Answer (score 13):

According to [JacksonFAQDateHandling](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling) page:

> All time objects that have associated TimeZone (java.util.Calendar
>   etc) that Jackson constructs **use** the standard timezone (GMT), **not** the
>   local time zone (whatever that might be). That is: Jackson defaults to
>   using GMT for all processing *unless* specifically told otherwise.

In your case, it looks like the date is automatically being converted to GMT/UTC. Try to provide your local timezone explicitly to avoid UTC conversion [as mentioned in the question *How come this time is off by 9 hours? (5 hours, 3 hours etc)* on same page]:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd/MM/yyyy", timezone="EST")
```

Secondly, I think you are using `Date.toString()` to print date. [Note](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199245) that java `Date` class is timezone independent but its `toString()` method uses the system's *default* timezone before printing.

Here it looks like `24/07/2015 00:00 UTC` is being converted to `23/07/2015 19:00 EST` by `toString()`. Both of these represent the same *moment* of time but in different timezones.

Comment: i don't use toString(), but surely when @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"), toString is maybe called. Is there a standard solution to manage this? keep only gmt date... but would need to know the timezone of the user somewhere to display date correctly. Maybe something could be used with new Date of java 8 or joda?

Comment: Best practice is to store the date/time info in UTC in database and also store user's timezone. Then use that timezone when displaying dates to user or remove timezone offset before storing. There are many articles listing benefits of this approach i.e. application can support different timezones. Java8 Date API has provided a new set of classes to work with date/time. Here is a nice article on Java8 Date API https://dzone.com/articles/deeper-look-java-8-date-and. Java8 or Joda _simplifies_ the date/timezone handling.

Answer (score 1):

AimZ answer is what pointed me to this but I added these three lines to my application.properties file and achieved the same thing

spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd

spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps:false

spring.jackson.time-zone:EST

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Using postman to verify that the client is not the culprit. Seems like an issue with the timezone Jackson is using vs the timezone of the system. Had to change the Jackson config to compensate for dates

```
@Configuration

public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {
        final Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.timeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
        jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        return jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in **JavaScript** when selecting dates from a datepicker. I formatted the fields using **.toString()** method but the function gave me a different date (I was messing a day as well). Like this:

`var mydate = new Date('2020-04-03');
console.log(mydate.toString());`

`//Thu Apr 02 2020 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

I fixed it ussing **.toUTCString()** instead.

```
var mydate = new Date('2020-04-03');

console.log(mydate.toUTCString());

//Fri, 03 Apr 2020 00:00:00 GMT
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in java. You can use ObjectMapper to set to default timezone

```
ObjectMapper mapper = ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter).getObjectMapper();
mapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

Solution here: [Jackson @JsonFormat set date with one day less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822877/jackson-jsonformat-set-date-with-one-day-less)

Full configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    for (HttpMessageConverter converter : converters) {
        if (converter instanceof org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter).getObjectMapper();
            mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());
            mapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same problem this week. For us the problem was the Decoder that we were using.
Our project is using feing and to decode our JSON we were using JacksonDecoder, so we changed to GsonDecoder, so problem solved.

```
private fun servico(): IUsuarioServiceDeskClient {
    return Feign.builder()
        .options(Request.Options(240000, 240000))
        .client(ApacheHttpClient()) 
        .encoder(JacksonEncoder())
        .decoder(GsonDecoder())
        .errorDecoder(SincServiceDeskErrorDecoder(urlBase))
        .target(IUsuarioServiceDeskClient::class.java, urlBase)
}
```