# Springboot getting UTC+1 instead of GMT when called from endpoint

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, tomcat

I actually have an issue with dates when they are called from an endpoint :

The date returned is one hour **before** UTC+1

But on the database the date is correct (UTC+1)

And when debugging the date from my object is also correct (UTC+1)

I have the following setUp  :

*Main.java :*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
  @PostConstruct
  void started() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
  }
```

I have set Hibernate to the following timezone :

*application.properties :*

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = Europe/Paris
```

I get the correct date before posting it :

[image: Date before post]

Date from database (took 4 minutes to post because the programm was on pause) :

[image: Date from database]

**Date from postman when calling endpoint**

[image]

Anyone has any idea on why the date when returned throught an endpoint seems to be a GMT ?

Comment: What are you using to create the response, jackson maybe?  If so try adding a date format

Comment: Thank you sir, it solved my issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from vickirk pointed that the problem was related to Jackson

You need to add a timezone to your JsonFormat annotation
Like this :

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", timezone = "Europe/Paris")
@Column(name = "date_creation", nullable = true)
protected Date dateCreation;
```

The related issue can be found there :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31838669/5186678