# JAVA: parse date with timezone

Tags: java, date

I read a lot of advices on internet and StackOverFlow, but still I'm not understanding why I'm getting this issue on this Date parse.
can someone help?

My code:

```
String date = " Aug 24 18:29:51 2017 GMT ";
System.out.println("@"+date+"@");
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(" MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy z ");
Date data = format.parse(date);
System.out.println("#"+data+"#");
```

Output:

```
@ Aug 24 18:29:51 2017 GMT @
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: " Aug 24 18:29:51 2017 GMT "
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
...
...
```

Comment: I believe you'll find an answer to your question at [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112357/java-simpledateformatyyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-gives-timezone-as-ist)

Comment: Are you sure this is a good representation of the code you're actually running? This snippet works just fine on my machine.

Comment: This code is working fine, could you please check your imports java.util.Date etc

Comment: If you’ve read a lot, then you have also read that you should avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your default `Locale` doesn't cope with the english word for the month of August.

You may want to force the English `Locale` :

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(" MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy z ", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: I don't have another explanation myself, but it does seem very weird that OP's locale cannot parse a date that it formatted itself.

Comment: @kumesana - how do you conclude that from the question?

Comment: @rustyx by misreading it. For some reason I thought at one moment the code formatted the date with the month as 'Aug'. I was wrong.

Comment: yes adding this Locale.ENGLISH i fixed, but why is so relevant? thanks

@ Aug 24 18:29:51 2017 GMT @
#Thu Aug 24 20:29:51 CEST 2017#

Comment: @MattVegas What do you mean why is it relevant? In French, August is written Août. As you can see, a 'g' has no reason to be there when wanting to describe August in this language. So there are languages where 'Aug' just cannot be parsed as August, nor as anything at all. That should feel obvious.

Comment: @MattVegas : That's just the timezone that `Date.toString()` displays (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199217/what-time-zone-does-date-tostring-display), there is nothing wrong with the value, but you may want to create another `DateFormat` to format you `Date` to the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your locale using **Locale.getDefault()**. You might have to set this to english.